# Selecting from a range based on multiple range criteria

Tags: sql

I have an interesting quandary here.

Imagine I have a list of numbers as follows: 2, 4, 9. Let's call them `foo`.

Now imagine I have the following data:

```
| Id | ForeignKey | RangeStart | RangeEnd |
|----|------------|------------|----------|
| 1  | 1          | 1          | 3        |
| 2  | 1          | 4          | 5        |
| 3  | 1          | 6          | 9        |
| 4  | 2          | 1          | 2        |
| 5  | 2          | 3          | 3        |
| 6  | 2          | 4          | 9        |
| 7  | 3          | 1          | 5        |
| 8  | 3          | 6          | 9        |
```

I need to find any rows where any of the items from `foo` fall in between `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd`. In this example, Row Id 5 would not be included in the result set, but all other rows would.

It's an easy enough problem to solve in my controller (just filter out the results in a loop), but I'm wondering if there isn't a set-based solution to this problem.

Comment: will you pass the *list* to the query?

Comment: Yes, we're actually using Dapper, so it is interpolated as a list of numbers, however we can pass it in anyway we need to. The trick is that the list of numbers being passed in is arbitrarily long (and optional), so we can't just make them different parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZYXV90335)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.*
FROM table1
JOIN foo
  ON foo.value between `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd`
```

[image]
**OUTPUT**

Comment: i don't think foo is a table based on OP's explanation.

Comment: @vkp OP say `"however we can pass it in anyway we need to."`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza ..sorry i did not see that.

Comment: It never really occurred to me to transform it into a table, but that makes it extremely easy. Thanks for the perspective. Academically, though, I am still curious if there's a way to do it as a list of integers.

Comment: @vkp me neither I start doing list at first too. Let me take another look to list.

Comment: To use a list depend on your rdbms, and how you send it. for example you have `unnest` in postgres, that just convert one array to table, and then can use this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * 
from    MyTable t
where   exists (select null from foo f where f.val between t.RangeStart and t.RangeEnd)
```